# how to change powerpoint text box background color using applescript?

Tags: applescript, powerpoint, shapes

I need to change selected (shape)Textbox background and outer line color , How can we do that ?[image]

Comment: Have a look here for lots of good examples of using AppleScript to automate PPT:  http://www.mactech.com/vba-transition-guide/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    set theShapeRange to shape range of selection of active window
    set n to (count shapes of theShapeRange)
    repeat with i from 1 to n
        tell shape i of theShapeRange
            set back color of fill format of it to {0, 200, 255}
            set fore color of line format of it to {255, 0, 0}
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: jack , When i applying same code twice to one shape its showing dots in-between the latest applied color pattern.Why its happening , I think its not replacing previous color. ? is it right ?

Comment: Try `set fore color of fill format of it` instead of `back color`

Comment: When i am grouped the n shapes in one group, and selected one shape from group and changed the color, but its changing color of all shapes in that group, how to overcome this jack? ,I need to change the color of that specific shape from that group.

Comment: Any one  know how to add custom attributes to slides in presentation using apple script?